# What is the big-O complexity to test for the equality of two hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash, big-o

I assume the answer is O(hash_equals) = n but am I correct?

E.g. in Ruby, we have:

```
$ irb
2.6.3 :001 > {a: 1, b: 2, c:3} == {b:2, a:1, c:3}
 => true
```

The implementation of that `==` is here:
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L3567

EDIT:  Per @Schwern (in a comment below), let's assume a flat hash with simple values.  My particular interest is for Ruby, but I'm also interested in the more general question in most languages / hash implementations.

Comment: Can we assume this is a flat hash with simple values?

Comment: Benchmark and find out. Theoretical doesn't matter. Only practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash comparisons are, on average, O(keys) + ∑Cost(value).

If the values are simple then comparing each value is O(1). The hash comparison is O(keys) + ∑O(1) which is O(keys).

Ruby does a few extra things, but the basic algorithm is simple.

1. [If they're the same hash, they're equal](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/660c7e050f6cb050fd5618f812129c211af29810/hash.c#L3571).
2. [If they have a different number of keys, they're not equal](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/660c7e050f6cb050fd5618f812129c211af29810/hash.c#L3588).
3. [If any pair in hash1 is not in hash2, they're not equal](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/660c7e050f6cb050fd5618f812129c211af29810/hash.c#L3597).
4. [They're equal](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/660c7e050f6cb050fd5618f812129c211af29810/hash.c#L3606).

```
def hash_eq(hash1, hash2)
  # O(1)
  return true if hash1.equal?(hash2)

  # O(1)
  return false if hash1.size != hash2.size

  # O(keys)
  hash1.each {|k,v|
    #               O(1)     O(value)
    return false if hash2[k] != v
  }

  return true
end
```

Checking object equality is just comparing two pointers, so O(1).

Ruby hashes store their size in `num_entries`, so comparing their size is O(1).

Iterating through the keys and values of a hash is O(keys), you're basically walking a array.

Looking up a value in a hash is O(1). Worst case is O(n), but this is exceedingly rare in modern hashes especially after it was found [to be a security issue](https://blogs.harvard.edu/dlarochelle/files/2012/01/perl_monger_hash_collisions.pdf).

Finally, comparing the values have their own cost. For simple values like numbers this is O(1). Anything else has its own cost which I'll call O(val). This can be large strings, which are O(n) where n is the size of the string, or complex nested data structures. We need to do this for each value and each value carries its own cost. I'll write this as the sum of all those costs: ∑Cost(value).

Thus O(1) + O(1) + O(keys) + ∑Cost(value). The O(1)s are swamped by O(keys) and disappear, thus O(keys) + ∑Cost(value).

---

A simple benchmark bears this out.

```
require 'benchmark'

def benchmark_hash_eq(&block)
  # We can't use h2 = h1.clone because that will not clone
  # the values. Then Ruby can cheat and use object equality to
  # compare the values.
  h1 = block.call
  h2 = block.call

  puts "Size: #{h1.size}"
  puts Benchmark.measure {
    10_000.times { h1 == h2 }
  }
end

puts "With number values"
benchmark_hash_eq do
  Hash[(1..100).collect { |i| [i, i] }]
end
benchmark_hash_eq do
  Hash[(1..1_000).collect { |i| [i, i] }]
end
benchmark_hash_eq do
  Hash[(1..10_000).collect { |i| [i, i] }]
end

puts "With large, equal size strings"
benchmark_hash_eq do
  Hash[(1..100).collect { |i| [i, "a" * 1000] }]
end
benchmark_hash_eq do
  Hash[(1..1_000).collect { |i| [i, "a" * 1000] }]
end
benchmark_hash_eq do
  Hash[(1..10_000).collect { |i| [i, "a" * 1000] }]
end
```

```
With number values
Size: 100
  0.019237   0.000043   0.019280 (  0.019306)
Size: 1000
  0.195047   0.000515   0.195562 (  0.196367)
Size: 10000
  1.913112   0.003115   1.916227 (  1.920030)

With large, equal size strings
Size: 100
  0.065414   0.000225   0.065639 (  0.065839)
Size: 1000
  0.669863   0.001145   0.671008 (  0.672279)
Size: 10000
 10.041987   0.013201  10.055188 ( 10.066840)
```

Perfectly linear, except that last one which could be due to the hash size reaching some memory threshold.

Note that Ruby can do the comparison in parallel. This doesn't change the complexity, but might make it perform faster.